# How chemists find out the electronic properties of elements (atomic numbers)

Tags: periodic-table, history-of-chemistry

How did chemists find how many electrons, neutrons, and protons each element had?

I mean I can understand the Mendeleev's table but without really knowing how you make one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One could do it in the following way.

1. The atomic number $Z$ can be determined by examining the x-ray spectrum of an atom.
   The frequency $f$ of the so-called *K-alpha line* is related to the atomic number $Z$ by [Moseley's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moseley%27s_law)
   $$
       \sqrt f = k_1 \cdot \left(Z - k_2\right) \, .
   $$
2. The atom is electrically neutral, so the number of electrons is obviously calculated from the atomic number.
3. And the number of neutrons is also simply to choose: the only requirement at this stage would be the correct atomic weight for the element in question.

Comment: Thanks based on your answer I was able to found the history http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number#History . Also it's important to understand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_weight